# How to select first parent DIV using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

```
var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' '); // this gets the current element classes

var classes = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' '); // this gets the parent classes.
```

The parent in the above situation is an ankor.

If I wanted to get the first parent DIV of $(this) what would the code look like?

```
var classes = $(this).div:parent().attr('class').split(' '); // just a quick try.
```

*** Basically I want to get the classes of the first parent DIV of $(this).

thx

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Use [**`.closest()`**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up the DOM tree up to the specified selector.

```
var classes = $(this).parent().closest('div').attr('class').split(' '); // this gets the parent classes.
```

Comment: `parents("div")` is traversing and returns all the parent div's you should use `.eq(0)` after it to make sure it returns just the one you want

Comment: Remember that it's better for performance to use `.parents('div').eq(0)` -- using that purse CSS selector FOLLOWED by jQuery to filter to just the first element will give you a slight performance boost -- see the 'Additional Notes' section on the [jQuery :eq doc](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Comment: @NoahWhitmore Fixed it. Used `closest()` so it wouldn't return all parents but the `div` parent.

Answer (score 45):

Use `.closest()`, which gets the first ancestor element that matches the given selector `'div'`:

```
var classes = $(this).closest('div').attr('class').split(' ');
```

EDIT:

As @Shef noted, `.closest()` will return the current element if it happens to be a DIV also. To take that into account, use `.parent()` first:

```
var classes = $(this).parent().closest('div').attr('class').split(' ');
```

Comment: `.closest()` will match itself if `$(this)` is a DIV element.

Comment: @Shef, that was new info to me, thanks. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: you could simply use `.parents("div").eq(0)`

Answer (score 8):

This gets parent if it is a div. Then it gets class.

```
var div = $(this).parent("div");
var _class = div.attr("class");
```

Comment: @meo That's what the question asked.

Answer (score 5):

two of the best options are

```
$(this).parent("div:first")

$(this).parent().closest('div')
```

and of course you can find the class attr by

```
$(this).parent("div:first").attr("class")

$(this).parent().closest('div').attr("class")
```

and for you

```
$(this).parent("div:first").attr("class").split(' ')
$(this).parent().closest('div').attr("class").split(' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple!

```
var classes = $(this).parent('div').attr('class');
```