# How to get top most div parent class

Tags: jquery, class, selector

I need to get the main `culpritClass` div class that holds everything after something is typed and enter is pressed and put it into a variable as a string.

I can't seem to get the class.

HTML:

```html
<div class="culpritClass">
<div class="inner" style="display: block;">
<div class="inner_chat"></div>
<form>
<textarea class="chat_text"></textarea> 
</form>     
</div><a class="culpritClass" href="#">culprit</a>
</div>
```

I tried the following JS but I get `undefined`.

```js
$('.chat_text').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == '13') {

        var ru = $(this).prev().parent().attr('class');

        alert(ru);
    }
});
```

The `var ru` is the line that matters.

Comment: If you know that `.culpritClass` is what you want to find you can use `.closest(".culpritClass")`. Is that OK?

Comment: Read This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089229/how-to-select-first-parent-div-using-jquery you can understand better

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var ru = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('class');
```

should do the trick. Even though this doesn't look like it is the neatest solution, it is the most straightforward one imo. Unless there's a function to pass an argument to a function which travels a number up, e.g. `ancestor(3)` which would travel three levels up in the DOM and return that element.

But if you are just trying to find the class itself, try closest.

```
var ru = $(this).closest('.culpritClass');
```

Comment: I don't know the class name upfront, I thought that went without saying. This is simple and perfect for my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try this: use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.chat_text').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == '13') {
       var ru = $(this).closest('.culpritClass').attr('class');
       alert(ru);
    }
});
```

You can either do like this:

```
var ru = $(this).parents().find('div').eq(0).attr('class');
```

or like this:

```
var ru = $(this).parents().find('div:first').attr('class');
```

Though there are so many ways to do this, you can select the way you like :)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KsvdK/34/)

Comment: You are selecting by `.culpritClass` and again you are finding the `attr class`, itswill not give you the same `culpritClass class`?

Comment: The OP needs to get main `.cuppritClass` so it would rather simple to use `.closest('.culpritClass')`

Answer (score 3):

Since you are reusing the `.culpritClass`, for the sake of precision and to avoid multiple `parent()` calls, use the [**`parents()`**](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) method with the class of that element as its selector:

```js
$('.chat_text').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == '13') {
    alert($(this).parents('.culpritClass').attr('class'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Place the cursor below and press ENTER</h3>
<div class="culpritClass">
  <div class="inner" style="display: block;">
    <div class="inner_chat"></div>
    <form>
      <textarea class="chat_text"></textarea>
    </form>
  </div><a class="culpritClass" href="#">culprit</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(this).closest('selector').find('div:first').attr('class');
```

If you want the `parents` `.culpritClass` first element then try this,

```
 $(this).closest('.culpritClass').find('div:first').attr('class');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `$(this).parents('.culpritClass')` or if you don't "know" the class, but you know that it has 3 parents exactly, then `$(this).parent().parent().parent()`

The problem in your JS is that the textarea has no `prev()`, you should change that too `parent()` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
var ru = $(this).parent('form').parent('div').parent('div').attr('class');
```

instead of

```
var ru = $(this).prev().parent().attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.chat_text').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == '13') {                
            var ru = $(this).closest("div").parent();               
            alert($(ru).html());
        }
    });
```

});

Comment: Note that in the question the user wants the 3rd div going up and not the closest.