# How to get the id of the div which is before the table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a `div` and it contains `table` like before

```
  <div id='divid'>
     <table>
       <tbody>
          <tr id="clicktr">
             <td> Some content</td>             
          <tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
```

javascript code:

```
  $("#clicktr").live('click',function(e){
       console.log($(this).parent().parent().attr('id'));
  });
```

On row click i want to get the id of the div how can i get that.
But i am not able to the id of the div

Comment: Still using `.live`, depreciated and removed in 1.9v.

Comment: Check this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089229/how-to-select-first-parent-div-using-jquery). Your question sounds very similar.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use **.closest()**. This will traverse up the DOM tree to find the first instance of a div.

You should also use **.on()** as the **.live()** method is deprecated.

```
$('table').on('click', '#clicktr', function(){
    var ID = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
});
```

On another note, if there are multiple tables and divs, you do not want to use the same ID for the **tr**'s, but instead a class.

Comment: Perhaps use `$("table").on("click", "tr", ...)` as a replacement for `.live()`?

Comment: if i have more div's how can i find the exact div. can i give any attribute like name

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is depreciated in v1.7 and removed in v1.9.  So use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#clicktr").on('click',function(){
       console.log($(this).parent().closest('div').attr("id"));
});
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RgxYQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this...

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/K3Xy6/1/

```
$('table tr td').click(function(e){
    var divId = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    alert(divId);
 });
```