# get first parent div in jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, anchor

I have the following code

```
<div id="parent">   
 <p>
 <a id="anchor"></a>
 </p>    
</div>
```

I have the following click event

```
 $("#anchor").click(function (e) {
 //need to find the first parent div id here 
}
```

Any idea how to find the parent div of the anchor tag ?

Comment: parent div of which element?

Comment: Your HTML in invalid. Spans can't have paragraphs as children.

Comment: This question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089229/how-to-select-first-parent-div-using-jquery

Comment: sorry.. i removed that

Comment: `id` should be unique in a single document. So in your case you can access your div like this: `$('#parent')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select first parent DIV using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089229/how-to-select-first-parent-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#anchor").click(function (e) {
   var parentDiv = $(this).closest('div');
   //To get ID
   var divID=$(this).closest('div').attr('id');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to replace id's if you have more then one instance of the mentioned html fragment in your document. Use classes instead.

```
$(document).on('click','.anchor', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $(e.target),
        $parent = $target.closest('div.parent');

})
```